# One method of class works, the other is undefined for the type?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Working on an assignment for my computing class, I've run into a roadblock. Of the several methods I have made in a separate class, one of them isn't working. I cannot see any reason why. I have made a Student object class with several methods involved. as an example, I will show that my .calcFinalGrade() method works, but that my .dataRecord() method says it is incompatible with the type student. The method .dataRecord() is declared below .calcFinalGrade() within the same class, and they both return simple statements (a double and a string).

Here is the code for the StudentObject class

```
public class StudentObject
{
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String studentNo;

 private double[] marks;
 private double midTerm;
 private double finalExam;

 private double finalGrade;
 private String letterGrade;

public void Student (String lastName, String firstName, String studentNo, double mark1, double mark2, double mark3, double mark4, double midTerm, double finalExam)
 {
      double[] inputMarks = {mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, midTerm, finalExam};
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.studentNo = studentNo;
      marks = inputMarks;
}



public double calcFinalGrade()
 {
   finalGrade = (((marks[0]+marks[1]+marks[2]+marks[3])/20)*0.075+(marks[4]/100)*0.30+(marks[5]/100)*0.40)*100;
   return finalGrade;
 }


public String dataRecord()
 {
   String dataR = (lastName+ ", "+ firstName+ ",  "+ midTerm+ ", "+finalExam);
   return dataR;
 }
```

And for Simplicity while asking for help this is a simple example of trying to call the two methods:

```
public class StudentProject
{

static Student[] students = new Student[0];  

public static void main (String[]args)
{

  System.out.println(students[0].calcFinalGrade());
  System.out.println(students[0].dataRecord());
}
```

I have omitted most of the code from the Main method for simplicity in answering this question. the Student objects are in arrays called students. The Students are scanned in from a file.

Both methods are declared in the same class and return such simple statements. But why is is that .calcFinalGrade() works and .dataRecord() doesn't when called from the same object??

Whenever I try to compile I get an error regarding .dataRecord() saying:

"The method dataRecord() is undefined for the type Student"

Appreciate any help for this before I get any more grey hairs

Comment: Where's your `Student` class defined?  I see a `StudentObject` and a `StudentProject`.

Comment: sorry, I retitled the Student class as StudentObject at one point. I also omitted the Student constructor for conciseness.

Comment: If you renamed the class but are still using the old name in `StudentProject`, there's your problem.

Comment: Tried sorting out my naming of class files, copied and pasted the code and changed around what needed to be changed.  Now i have an issue with my Student Constructor method being defined. Definitely onto something here now though, thanks a lot! I was totally overlooking that.

Comment: Do you realize that `public void Student (String lastName, String firstName, String studentNo, double mark1, double mark2, double mark3, double mark4, double midTerm, double finalExam)` is not a constructor?

Comment: I just came back to say I noticed I did this, I removed void from my Student contructors, Problem solved!